# Is it possible to get more detailed error from 'flush result'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-analytics

iOS 10, 9. FB SDK - iOS-4.25.0

When I'm sending an event to facebook analytics I'm getting

Flush Result : No Connectivity

Doesn't matter if it's custom event or one from automatic handling.

I've checked fb app through and through - everything should be working. I've checked code - also should be working. One project works perfectly while another one constantly throws me that on iOS. I am logged into facebook on device and simulator, but still this issue.

Is there a way to get more detailed info about that error so I at least know what is wrong?